# Excluding symlinks from intellisense in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Symlinking a folder from within the same workspace causes VSCode to list both the original folder and the symlinked one in IntelliSense when importing files.

Example:

`a/
  b/
c/
  d/ -> ../b/`

Causes IntelliSense to suggest both modules from `a/b` and `c/d`.

Is there any way to exclude the symlinked folders from IntelliSense other than excluding them in `tsconfig.json` (which for certain reasons we cannot easily do).